wt visual studio ressources not found
I'm traying to set up development environment with visual sudio and wt.
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << "my directory is " << ExePath() << "\n";
    return Wt::WRun(argc, argv, [](const Wt::WEnvironment& env) {
      return std::make_unique<TacTicaWebView>(env);
    });
}

TacTicaWebView::TacTicaWebView(const Wt::WEnvironment& env)
    : Wt::WApplication(env)
{
    setTitle("TacTica");
    mRootContainer = root()->addNew <Wt::WContainerWidget>();

    // Create a navigation bar with a link to a web page.
    Wt::WNavigationBar* navigation = mRootContainer->addNew<Wt::WNavigationBar>();
    navigation->setTitle("TacTica");

    Wt::WStackedWidget* contentsStack = mRootContainer->addNew<Wt::WStackedWidget>();
    contentsStack->addStyleClass("contents");

    // Setup a Left-aligned menu.
    auto leftMenu = std::make_unique<Wt::WMenu>(contentsStack);
    auto leftMenu_ = navigation->addMenu(std::move(leftMenu));

    auto searchResult = std::make_unique<Wt::WText>("Buy or Sell... Bye!");
    auto searchResult_ = searchResult.get();

    leftMenu_->addItem("Home", std::make_unique<Wt::WText>("There is no better place!"));
    leftMenu_->addItem("Layout", std::make_unique<Wt::WText>("Layout contents"));
    leftMenu_->addItem("Sales", std::move(searchResult));
   // leftMenu_->addStyleClass("me-auto");

    // Add a Search control.
    auto editPtr = std::make_unique<Wt::WLineEdit>();
    auto edit = editPtr.get();
    edit->setPlaceholderText("Enter a search item");

    edit->enterPressed().connect([=] {
        leftMenu_->select(2); // is the index of the "Sales"
        searchResult_->setText(Wt::WString("Nothing found for {1}.")
            .arg(edit->text()));
        });

    navigation->addSearch(std::move(editPtr));

    // Setup a Right-aligned menu.
    auto rightMenu = std::make_unique<Wt::WMenu>();
    auto rightMenu_ = navigation->addMenu(std::move(rightMenu));

    // Create a popup submenu for the Help menu.
    auto popupPtr = std::make_unique<Wt::WPopupMenu>();
    auto popup = popupPtr.get();
    popup->addItem("Contents");
    popup->addItem("Index");
    popup->addSeparator();
    popup->addItem("About");

    useStyleSheet("style/wt.css");
    useStyleSheet("resources/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css");
    useStyleSheet("style/widgetgallery.css");
    useStyleSheet("style/everywidget.css");
    useStyleSheet("style/pygments.css");
    useStyleSheet("style/layout.css");
    useStyleSheet("style/filedrop.css");

    popup->itemSelected().connect([=](Wt::WMenuItem* item) {
#ifndef WT_TARGET_JAVA
        auto messageBox = popup->addChild(
            std::make_unique<Wt::WMessageBox>
#else // WT_TARGET_JAVA
        auto messageBox = new Wt::WMessageBox
#endif // WT_TARGET_JAVA
            ("Help",
                Wt::WString("<p>Showing Help: {1}</p>").arg(item->text()),
                Wt::Icon::Information,
#ifndef WT_TARGET_JAVA
                Wt::StandardButton::Ok));
#else // WT_TARGET_JAVA
            Wt::WFlags<Wt::StandardButton>(Wt::StandardButton::Ok));
#endif // WT_TARGET_JAVA

        messageBox->buttonClicked().connect([=] {
#ifndef WT_TARGET_JAVA
            popup->removeChild(messageBox);
#else // WT_TARGET_JAVA
            delete messageBox;
#endif // WT_TARGET_JAVA
            });

        messageBox->show();
        });

    auto item = std::make_unique<Wt::WMenuItem>("Help");
    item->setMenu(std::move(popupPtr));
    rightMenu_->addItem(std::move(item));
}

I put the ressuces files and style on the application directory.

And I run debug with options as indicted ont the wt tutorial

I got the following errors :
[2024-Jun-06 11:03:42.324] 35796 - [info] "wthttp: 127.0.0.1   GET /resources/themes/default/wt.css HTTP/1.1 404 85"
[2024-Jun-06 11:03:42.324] 35796 - [info] "wthttp: 127.0.0.1   GET /resources/moz-transitions.css HTTP/1.1 404 85"
[2024-Jun-06 11:03:42.325] 35796 - [info] "wthttp: 127.0.0.1   GET /style/wt.css HTTP/1.1 404 85"
[2024-Jun-06 11:03:42.325] 35796 - [info] "wthttp: 127.0.0.1   GET /resources/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1 404 85"
[2024-Jun-06 11:03:42.325] 35796 - [info] "wthttp: 127.0.0.1   GET /style/widgetgallery.css HTTP/1.1 404 85"[2024-Jun-06 11:03:42.325] 35796 - [info] "wthttp: 127.0.0.1   GET /style/everywidget.css HTTP/1.1 404 85"[2024-Jun-06 11:03:42.326] 35796 - [info] "wthttp: 127.0.0.1   GET /style/layout.css HTTP/1.1 404 85"
[2024-Jun-06 11:03:42.326] 35796 - [info] "wthttp: 127.0.0.1   GET /style/pygments.css HTTP/1.1 404 85"
[2024-Jun-06 11:03:42.326] 35796 - [info] "wthttp: 127.0.0.1   GET /style/filedrop.css HTTP/1.1 404 85"
[2024-Jun-06 11:

See where it says Working Directory right under the Command Arguments? You probably need to set that to the directory where your content is or modify the path you have in the arguments to be relative to the project directory.

Is the folder shown in the first picture the one with the project file so its the one set as the working directory?

Thank you changing the working directory solved the problem

As  Retired Ninja said,
you need to set the Working Directory  option to the directory where your content is located, or modify the path in the arguments to make it relative to your project directory
